# Problem with chemistry packages

Tags: chemistry, mhchem, chemformula

I have been using `\usepackage{mhchem}` to write chemical equations. Now I want to use also `\usepackage{chemformula}`. But when I use the second package it appears that LaTeX doesn't understand the keywords of the first package.

Is it possible? Any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: The two are similar but not identical, as detailed below: 'pick one'!

Comment: Like I said, similar but not identical: `chemformula` assumes text mode and is arguably more focussed. In your example `\Delta G` isn't a chemistry formula so shouldn't be in either of the forms: just `$\Delta G$` would be appropriate.

Comment: @JosephWright $\Delta G$ as you wrote, is italic. I have read the packages and mhchem seems to be prepared for writing Deltas and so on, why do you say it is not?

Comment: Yes: it's a variable (Gibbs energy): see for example _Physical Chemistry_ by Atkins which is typeset carefully and has this form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a user of either of the mentioned packages, `mhchem` and  `chemformula`.

From the [documentation of `chemformula`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemformula/chemformula_en.pdf):

> Probably every chemist using LaTeX2ε is aware of the great `mhchem`
>   package by Martin Hensel. There have always been some difficulties
>   intertwining it with the `chemmacros` package, though. Also,
>   some other minor points in `mhchem` always bothered me, but they hardly
>   seemed enough for a new package. They weren’t even enough for a
>   feature request to the `mhchem` author. The challenge and the fun of
>   creating a new package and the wish for a highly customizable
>   alternative led to `chemformula` after all. `chemformula`
>   works very similar to mhchem but is more strict as to how
>   compounds, stoichiometric factors and arrows are input. In the same
>   time `chemformula` offers many possibilities to customize the
>   output.

Though not mentioned explicitly, I have a feeling that these two package are not compatible. But your purposes should be served by either of the packages.

---

`chemmacros` is a comprehensive support for typesetting chemistry documents.

Either `mhchem` or  `chemformula` can be loaded as modules:

```
formula = chemformula|mhchem
```

Default: `chemformula`.

If you set `formula = {chemformula}`, the `chemformula`
module makes it possible that you can set all `chemformula` options via the `\chemsetup`
command using the module `chemformula`, for example:

```
\chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}
```

And if you set `formula = {mhchem}`, the `chemformula` module makes
it possible that you can set all of `mhchem`’s options via the `\chemsetup` command using the
module `mhchem`, for example:

```
\chemsetup[mhchem]{format=\sffamily}
```

*(The last examples also implicitly indicate that either `mhchem` or `chemformula` should be used in a document, but not both.)*

Comment: @santimirandarp Please see my edit at the end of my answer. And you are most welcome.

Comment: @santimirandarp Yes, of course, isn't that expected? You will have to adapt to a style and stick to it. Again, my knowledge on these packages is limited, I don't (don't need to) use either.

Comment: It should not be a problem to use both packages in one document. However, for conistent typeset formulas and reactions I wouldn't use both. They use different spacing, different arrows, ...

Comment: @clemens great, would you recommend one?

Comment: @santimirandarp I am biased: I'm the author of `chemformula`… :)

Comment: @clemens ohh..haha. This place is wonderful. Well that the one I chose finally..I hope it works good!